# java generic comparable idiom

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I encountered the following piece of a definition for a generic class:

```
public class binarysearchnode<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<binarysearchnode<T>>{
.............
}
```

Please help explaining why a class would specify itself as a Type parameter to comparable while implementing the comparable interface?
How would it be different from the following:

```
public class binarysearchnode<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<? super (or extends)T>{
.............
}
```

Comment: Because it's comparable to another instance of itself, not any random other thing. Look at the actual `compareTo()` method and this should be clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This makes it possible to compare `binarysearchnode`s to each other. If it implemented `Comparable<T>`, that would instead mean that the node could be compared to the **value** of the node, which would be odd.

Inside the class you will probably find something like this:

```
T value;

public int compareTo(binarysearchnode<T> other) {
   return value.compareTo(other.value);
}
```

In order to be able to implement `compareTo()` like this, the value class (`T`) needs to be comparable to other objects of its class - hence the declaration of `<T extends Comparable<T>>` in the class definition.

Answer (score 2):

It is because what the class author wants is to be able to write:

```
b1.compareTo(b2)
```

where `b1` and `b2` are `binarysearchnode` instances. The developer also *adds a constraint to `T`* so that `T` extends `Comparable<T>`. Probably so that the implementation of `Comparable` for `binarysearchnode` can just rely on `T` instances being `Comparable` themselves.

More generally, while it is possible for a class `C1` to implement `Comparable<C2>`, ultimately, it makes no sense to do so: this does not mean that an instance of `C2` could be comparable to an instance of `C1`. And due to type erasure, it would not be possible, for instance, for class `C1` to implement *both* `Comparable<C1>` and `Comparable<C2>`.

Also, if `binarysearchnode<T>` were to implement `Comparable<T>` directly, you would have at least two problems:

- you would not be able to compare one `binarysearchnode<T>` to another;
- given a `binarysearchnote<T>` instance `b` and a `T` instance `t`, you would be able to write `b.compareTo(t)` but not `t.compareTo(b)` (since `T` does not, and cannot, implement `Comparable<binarysearchnode<T>>`), and that breaks the `Comparable` contract.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a superclass `A` and a subclass `B`. Imagine the superclass implements `Comparable<A>`, then `B` will also implement `Comparable<A>` through inheritance.

Your binarysearchnode class declared as such :

```
public class binarysearchnode<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

will not be able to take `B` as a type parameter for `T` (`B` does not implement `Comparable<B>`)
But when defined as such :

```
public class binarysearchnode<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

it will be able to take `B` as a type parameter for `T`, since `B` implements `Comparable<A>` which fulfills `Comparable<? super T>`.